# Unmarshalling XML using Go: How to find attributes with the same value?

Tags: xml, go

I'm having trouble unmarshalling the XML below, how do I find all `<info>` nodes with `type="Genres"` and store their values inside a `[]Genre`?

```
<manga id="4199" type="manga" name="Jinki: Extend" precision="manga">
    <info type="Main title" lang="EN">Jinki: Extend</info>
    <info type="Genres">action</info>
    <info type="Genres">science fiction</info>
    <info type="Themes">mecha</info>
    <info type="Number of tankoubon">9</info>
    <info type="Number of pages">186</info>
</manga>
```

I'm looking to store the values in structs similar to these:

```
// Manga struct
type Manga struct {
    WorkID    int     `xml:"id,attr"`
    Name      string  `xml:"name,attr"`
    Precision string  `xml:"precision,attr"`
    Genres    []Genre `[this is the part I need help on]`
}

// Genre struct
type Genre struct {
    Value string
}
```

I know the XML is not ideal, but it is what I have to work with, I hope you guys can help me with this.

Thanks in advance.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Since `<manga>` contains a list of `<info>` elements, it makes more sense to have a list of `Info` structs rather than trying to translate the `<info>` elements into various types. I would define the data structures like:

```
type Manga struct {
    WorkID    int    `xml:"id,attr"`
    Name      string `xml:"name,attr"`
    Precision string `xml:"precision,attr"`
    Info      []Info `xml:"info"`
}

type Info struct {
    Type  string `xml:"type,attr"`
    Value string `xml:",chardata"`
}
```

The output (json encoded for convenience) looks like:

```
{
  "WorkID": 4199,
  "Name": "Jinki: Extend",
  "Precision": "manga",
  "Info": [
    {
      "Type": "Main title",
      "Value": "Jinki: Extend"
    },
    {
      "Type": "Genres",
      "Value": "action"
    },
    {
      "Type": "Genres",
      "Value": "science fiction"
    },
    {
      "Type": "Themes",
      "Value": "mecha"
    },
    {
      "Type": "Number of tankoubon",
      "Value": "9"
    },
    {
      "Type": "Number of pages",
      "Value": "186"
    }
  ]
}
```

Answer (score 0):

In case the XML won't not very large, I would just write an utility function  like:

```
type Manga struct {
    WorkID    int    `xml:"id,attr"`
    Name      string `xml:"name,attr"`
    Precision string `xml:"precision,attr"`
    Info      []Info `xml:"info"`
}

type Info struct {
    Type string `xml:"type,attr"`
    Data string `xml:",chardata"`
}

func (m *Manga) Genres() []Info {
    var g []Info

    for _, v := range m.Info {
        if v.Type == "Genres" {
            g = append(g, v)
        }
    }
    return g

}
```

See it in action: https://play.golang.org/p/bebUwwbSwG